# How to load Admob ads after certain time of app load?

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

Hi I am creating an Android app. I want to show Interstitial ads after some time of app load. Say 60 seconds.

The Code that I had developed shows add instantly as soon as the App is launced, I need that it should be shown after a delay of say 60 sec. But in the mean time the App should perform the operation and should not wait or sleep.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    interAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice("SEE_YOUR_LOGCAT_TO_GET_YOUR_DEVICE_ID")
        .build();
    interAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    interAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override

        public void onAdLoaded() {
            displayinterstitial();
        }
    });
}

public void displayinterstitial() {
    if (interAd.isLoaded()) {
        interAd.show();
    }
}
```

Help me to resolve my issue.

Comment: Take a look at [Handler.postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Your code to show add

            }
        }, 60000);
```

Your new code would be

```
@Override
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            interAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
            interAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addTestDevice("SEE_YOUR_LOGCAT_TO_GET_YOUR_DEVICE_ID")
                    .build();
            interAd.loadAd(adRequest);
            interAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override

                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    displayinterstitial();
                }
            });

        }
    } , 60000);
}
```

Comment: Sir I am new to developing field. Could you please assist with the above code I posted? So If i am using your code block, how should my new code look likes?

Comment: interAd = new InterstitialAd(this);  showing error..    Error:(42, 27) error: constructor InterstitialAd in class InterstitialAd cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context
found: <anonymous Runnable>
reason: actual argument <anonymous Runnable> cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion

Comment: replace interAd = new InterstitialAd(this); with interAd = new InterstitialAd(YourClassName.this);

Comment: Sir you are great.. it worked...... Thanks.... interAd = new InterstitialAd(mainactivity.this);

Comment: Sir I have another doubt too.. How can I repeat the same procedure after 60 seconds? Any idea? I mean showing interstitial after 60 seconds period...

Comment: I had verified your answer. And up voted.. i have no 15 reputations.... So it wont come public. Sorry :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this it could help you.

```
interAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
            interAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addTestDevice("SEE_YOUR_LOGCAT_TO_GET_YOUR_DEVICE_ID")
                    .build();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

            interAd.loadAd(adRequest);

                }
            }, 1000); // After one Sec
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting this error   Error:(42, 27) error: constructor InterstitialAd in class InterstitialAd cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context
found: <anonymous Runnable>
reason: actual argument <anonymous Runnable> cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion